# Is there a better alternative to using sleep in Capybara?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, capybara

In my test I have a step where I fill out a field and press enter. This field then returns a result set on the next page.

Here is my helper method:

```
def search(term)
  fill_in('query-text', :with => term)
  click_button('search-button')
end
```

After that I have a step that simply says:

```
page.should have_content(tutor)
```

However, the issue is that even though the page after my page loads with the results, the step after it passes even if it should be false. I have set a debugger in the step and when I manually check it, the assertion fails as I expect it too. My assumption is that the the next step is checking before the page even reloads. I placed a sleep at the end of my search method to make it look like:

```
def search(term)
  fill_in('query-text', :with => term)
  click_button('search-button')
  sleep 5
end
```

But I feel like using sleep is a hacky way to resolve this issue. I am using Capybara 2 so the use of wait_until is removed. Is there a better way to handle this issue rather than relying on sleep?

Answer (score 5):

Do you have `tutor` text in your HTML page hidden? `has_content?` returns `true` for any text present in html, including hidden text which is not visible. So I would rather replace it with `expect(page).to have_text(tutor)`, which checks only for visible text on a page. `.text` is also pretty slow method, so these extra split seconds may be handy for you.

Another approach is to restore wait_until method in your spec helpers, since it's really handy in most cases:

```
def wait_until(timeout = DEFAULT_WAIT_TIME)
  Timeout.timeout(timeout) do
    sleep(0.1) until value = yield
    value
  end
end
```

In any case it will be better than waiting for a fixed timeout each time.

Answer (score 1):

This test passes as `tutor` is already present on the page.

So you should check not for `tutor` but for something else, e.g. for element with text `tutor` that is present only after page reload.

Answer (score 0):

yes, you're right wait_until is removed, new method is #synchronize, but I don't know for now how to use it:)

look into

http://www.elabs.se/blog/53-why-wait_until-was-removed-from-capybara

https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara/blob/master/lib/capybara/node/base.rb#L44

Comment: The first link clearly states that `synchronize` has a very different usecase than `wait_until`.

Comment: Not sure why this has been downvoted. The first link in this answer is relevant information.